# Sails production and development routes

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have sails backend, which has a few stubs routes, which need to be used only in development mode.

Do sails has a native way for specifying development and production (--prod key at the launching) routes or not? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the environment-specific config files for this.  In v0.10.x, put your dev-only routes in `config/env/development.js`:

```
module.exports = {

  routes: {

    "GET /mydevroute": "MyDevController.someAction"

  }

}
```

This will work in the upcoming v0.11.x as well, but you will also be able to use a per-environment subfolder, so you could create `config/env/development/routes.js`:

```
module.exports.routes = {

  "GET /mydevroute": "MyDevController.someAction"

}
```